# Is there a name for double underscore functions?

Tags: python

Is there a term for functions starting and ending with the double underscore (**init** or **getattr** for example)? I understand their purpose, just wondering if there is a good way to refer to them! Thanks!

Comment: I think this question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate. While the meaning of double underscore functions has been answered, my question was specifically about their name, and that was not answered by any of the top answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id29) refers to the functions or attributes starting and trailing with double underscore  as `"magic objects"` or `"magic attributes"`.

> **double_leading_and_trailing_underscore** : "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. **init** ,
>   **import** or **file** .

Comment: Ah there we go! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

I always heard them named "dunder functions" as a shortname for "double-underscore functions".

It's a name a bit surprising at first, but easy to say and understand when talking.

Comment: Haha, I like that! Thanks!